# Crystal Reports - Get data from a previous record with same ID

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I have a Crystal Report which is connected to an SQL database. I need to extract data from a previous record that has the same ID as the current ID.
For example:

```
ID          Name             Location
1           John             Home
2           Jane             work
3           peter            school
1           John             work
```

The ID is not a primary key but an asset ID tag and I need to display the previous location for each ID in my report. So `ID = '1'` would have a previous location of `work` because the current location is `Home` as its the latest record. I would need to display `work` as the previous location in the current record for that ID.

I am using Crystal Reports within Visual Studio 2015.

I hope that all makes sense. Please help; I have now been on this for a week.

Comment: So, nothing to do with MySQL?

Comment: Group by id and show the data in detail section

Comment: I am relatively new to crystal reports and i wouldn't know how to use SQL and crystal reports to achieve what i need? As for grouping, my data is already being grouped by another field and i dont think grouping is the answer as i only need to get the loction from the previous record with the same ID and insert that location into the current record as previous location.